# Scala named extractor for class with one parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Scala named extractors example:

```
class Foo1(n: Int) {
  def isEmpty: Boolean =
    false
  def get: Foo1 =
    this
  def _1: Int   = n
}

object Foo1 {
  def unapply(arg: Foo1) = arg
}

class Foo2(n: Int, nn: Int) {
  def isEmpty: Boolean =
    false
  def get: Foo2 =
    this
  def _1: Int   = n
  def _2: Int   = nn
}

object Foo2 {
  def unapply(arg: Foo2) = arg
}

object Main extends App {

  new Foo1(1) match {
    case Foo1(n) if n > 0 ⇒ println(n)
  }
  //Error: value > is not a member of Foo1
  //case Foo1(n) if n > 0 ⇒ println(n)

  new Foo2(1, 2) match {
    case Foo2(n, nn) if n > 0 ⇒ println(s"$n -> $nn")
  }
  // 1 -> 2
```

}

I'm curious about why Scala extracts class instance for one parameter(Foo1), but extracts parameters(Foo2(n,nn)) if their number > 1. Have I missed anything or it's intended behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think, the main reason for introducing named based extractors is the possibility to use value classes (extending AnyVal) to extract a single value instead of `def unapply(arg: Foo1): Options[Foo1]`. This way you can avoid an instantiation of an extra `Option` and thus garbage collection. Usually, this is used to extract values that meet certain criteria.

Example:

```
class PositiveNonZeroInteger(private val n: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = n <= 0
  def get: Int = n
}

object PositiveNonZeroInteger {
  def unapply(arg: Int) = new PositiveNonZeroInteger(arg)
}

1 match {
  case PositiveNonZeroInteger(pos) => "yay"
  case _                           => "nay"
} // => "yay"

0 match {
  case PositiveNonZeroInteger(pos) => "yay"
  case _                           => "nay"
} // => "nay"
```

It seems, the tuple getters (`_1, _2`) are probably only parsed by the compiler if at least two of them exist.

So if you'd rewrite your first foo to:

```
class Foo1(private val n: Int) /*extends AnyVal*/ {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  def get: Int = n
}

object Foo1 {
  def unapply(arg: Foo1) = arg
}
```

Your code would work but this is not what name based extractors are for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Scala language specification distinguishes the cases with 0, 1 or many parameters in an extractor pattern:

http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns

For 1 parameter it expects the an Option of the matched type, i.e. `Option[Int]` in the case of `Foo1`, and an `Option` of a tuple for more than one arguments.

In your example, if you want to return the instance itself from the `unapply` method you could duck-type the `Option[Int]` expected for `Foo1` by implementing

```
class Foo1(n: Int) {
  def get: Int = n
  ...
```

Comment: I try to avoid Option extra creation

Comment: Then use the get function that returns the int directly, as mentioned in my answer.